# How do I parse Volley JSON Object with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, lombok

I'm trying to parse this JSON Response:

```js
{
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "message": "App Version",
  "source": "Cache",
  "data": {
    "latestVersion": true,
    "link": "-"
  }
}
```

Here's the interface and volley instance code:

```js
public interface IResult {
  public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response);
  public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error);
}

public class VolleyService {

  IResult mResultCallback;
  Context mCtx;

  public VolleyService(IResult resultCallback, Context context) {
    mResultCallback = resultCallback;
    mCtx = context;
  }

  public void postData(final String requestType, String url, Map < String, String > data, Map < String, String > headers) {
    try {
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx);
      JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(data), response - > {
        if (mResultCallback != null)
          mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
      }, error - > {
        if (mResultCallback != null) {
          mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType, error);
          if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            new DialogBuilder(mCtx, "Error: 1");
          } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            new DialogBuilder(mCtx, "Error: 2");
          } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            new DialogBuilder(mCtx, "Error: 3");
          } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            new DialogBuilder(mCtx, "Error: 4");
          } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            new DialogBuilder(mCtx, "Error: 5");
          }
        }
      }) {
        @Override
        public Map < String, String > getHeaders() {
          return headers;
        }
      };
      queue.add(jsonObj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("postData", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

The JSONObject response is fetched from Volley and I try to parse the response with this code below:

```js
public class CheckForUpdate {

  private Context mCtx;
  private IResult mResultCallback = null;
  private Gson gson;

  public CheckForUpdate(Context mCtx) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
  }

  public void checkUpdate(String appVersion) {

    initVolleyCallback();
    VolleyService mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback, mCtx);

    Map < String, String > data = new HashMap < > ();
    data.put("show", "version");
    data.put("appVersion", appVersion);

    Map < String, String > header = new HashMap < > ();
    header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    mVolleyService.postData("checkUpdate", URLs.APP_VERSION, data, header);

  }

  void initVolleyCallback() {
    mResultCallback = new IResult() {
      @Override
      public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
        BaseResponseModel appVersion = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), BaseResponseModel.class);
        Log.e("appVersionJson", response.toString());
        Log.e("appVersion", "message: " + appVersion.getMessage());
      }

      @Override
      public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {

      }
    };
  }

}
```

I'm getting a null response in all those Logs.e, here's my models using Lombok look like:

BaseResponseModel.java

```js
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class BaseResponseModel<T> implements Serializable {
  private boolean error;
  private float code;
  private String message;
  private String source;
  private T data;
}
```

AppVersionModel.java

```js
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AppVersionModel implements Serializable {
  private boolean latestVersion;
  private String link;
}
```

How can I parse JSONObject response from Volley with Gson properly? What am I missing here?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Code snippets are rather useless for Java and you're lacking GSON annotations.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I apologized for the bad code snippets, the snippets are updated now. Kindly re-check the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the onCreate as well. It seems you haven't initialized GSon, GSon Builder.

```js
    Gson gson = new Gson();
```

The problem is here an empty constructor. Obviously it will retrieve null objects.
Try making use of [this](https://medium.com/quick-code/parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley-83d6715776f8) guide and work with it.

Comment: Hi, the code snippet are updated now, kindly re-check my question